# Log cabin support beam swing

Tags: swing

I own a log cabin and I put a hammock swing on the support beam in my living room.  Is this safe?  I have noticed the upstairs has a gap and I told the kids I won’t swing them anymore.  When I did swing them the full pine beam creaks.  I am not sure if I am being overly paranoid or if I was irresponsible for putting a rope swing up.

Comment: Swinging is hard on beams, almost twice of a steady weight hanging down.  Size of the beam, the open span, how the hammock is attached is all important information required in your question.

Comment: It’s about a 12” diameter pine beam.  The beam hangs over the entire living room, about 20 ft.It hangs down about 7 ft from a rope tied around the beam.

Comment: If the supports on the beam were tied at the very ends of the beam, leading diagonally down to the swing, it would lessen strain in the middle, where it flexes. That said, without more info, it's impossible to say how safe or dangerous that is.

Comment: Definitely need a _lot_ more info about span, beam size, pics (of the beam and the walls where it rests), etc. Please [edit] this info into your question.